# Keras pretrain CNN with TimeDistributed

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network, resnet

Here is my problem, I want to use one of the pretrain CNN network in a TimeDistributed layer. But I have some problem to implement it.

Here is my model:

```
def bnn_model(max_len):
    # sequence length and resnet input size
    x = Input(shape=(maxlen, 224, 224, 3))

    base_model = ResNet50.ResNet50(weights='imagenet',  include_top=False)

    for layer in base_model.layers:
        layer.trainable = False

    som = TimeDistributed(base_model)(x)

    #the ouput of the model is [1, 1, 2048], need to squeeze
    som = Lambda(lambda x: K.squeeze(K.squeeze(x,2),2))(som)

    bnn = Bidirectional(LSTM(300))(som)
    bnn = Dropout(0.5)(bnn)

    pred = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(bnn)

    model = Model(input=x, output=pred)

    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=1.0e-5), loss="mse", metrics=["accuracy"])

    return model
```

When compiling the model I have no error. But when I start training I get the following error:

```
tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_2' with dtype float
[[Node: input_2 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
```

I checked and I do send float32 but for input1, input2 is the input present in the pretrain Resnet.

Just to have an overview here is the model summary. (Note: it's strange that it doesn't show what happen inside Resnet but never mind)

```
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to                     
====================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)             (None, 179, 224, 224, 0                                            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
timedistributed_1 (TimeDistribut (None, 179, 1, 1, 204 23587712    input_1[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_1 (Lambda)                (None, 179, 2048)     0           timedistributed_1[0][0]          
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_1 (Bidirectional)  (None, 600)           5637600     lambda_1[0][0]                   
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)              (None, 600)           0           bidirectional_1[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                  (None, 1)             601         dropout_1[0][0]                  
====================================================================================================
Total params: 29,225,913
Trainable params: 5,638,201
Non-trainable params: 23,587,712
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

I am guessing that I do not use the TimeDistributed correctly and I saw nobody trying to do this. I hope someone can guide me on this.

EDIT:

The problem comes from the fact that `ResNet50.ResNet50(weights='imagenet',  include_top=False)` create its own input in the graph.

So I guess I need to do something like `ResNet50.ResNet50(weights='imagenet',  input_tensor=x, include_top=False)` but I do not see how to couple it with `TimeDistributed`.

I tried

```
base_model = Lambda(lambda x : ResNet50.ResNet50(weights='imagenet',  input_tensor=x, include_top=False))
som = TimeDistributed(base_model)(in_ten)
```

But it does not work.

Comment: It seems to ask for a float value for the placeholder. Could you trace down what's passed to the `feed_dict` in the `tf.Session.run` call?

Comment: In **tensorflow_backend.py** I printed the feed_dict and I got this `[<tf.Tensor 'input_1:0' shape=(?, 179, 224, 224, 3) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'dense_1_target:0' shape=(?, ?) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'keras_learning_phase:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=bool>, <tf.Tensor 'dense_1_sample_weights:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float32>]`. The ResNet is still defined with a placeholder when it should not.

Comment: I am pretty sure I should do something like `ResNet50.ResNet50(weights='imagenet',  input_tensor=x, include_top=False)` so there is not placeholder in the base_model but I do not see how to do it with TimeDistributed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My quick solution is a little bit ugly.

I just copied the code of ResNet and added TimeDistributed to all layers and then loaded the weights from a "basic" ResNet on my customized ResNet.

Note:

To be able to analyze sequence of images like this does take a huge amount of memory on the gpu.

Comment: Actually - there is no other way :< Your solution is currently the best possible.

Comment: It will run from scratch and not perform transfer learning. So useless.

Answer (score 4):

My simple solution is a pretty one.

Considering you are using a pre-trained network from keras, you can replace it with your own pre-trained network too.

Here's a simple solution::

```
model_vgg=keras.applications.VGG16(input_shape=(256, 256, 3),
                                           include_top=False,
                                           weights='imagenet')
model_vgg.trainable = False
model_vgg.summary()
```

If you want to use any intermediate layers then, otherwise replace 'block2_pool' with last layer's name::

```
intermediate_model= Model(inputs=model_vgg.input, outputs=model_vgg.get_layer('block2_pool').output)
intermediate_model.summary()
```

Finally wrap it in a TimeDistributed Layer

```
input_tensor = Input(shape=(time_steps,height, width, channels))
timeDistributed_layer = TimeDistributed( intermediate_model )(input_tensor)
```

Now you can simply do::

```
my_time_model = Model( inputs = input_tensor, outputs = timeDistributed_layer )
```

Comment: How do we get multiple layers for skip connection like in UNET architecture?