# Combining CNN with LSTM using Tensorflow Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, lstm

I'm using pre-trained ResNet-50 model and want to feed the outputs of the penultimate layer to a LSTM Network. Here is my sample code containing only CNN (ResNet-50):

```
N = NUMBER_OF_CLASSES
#img_size = (224,224,3)....same as that of ImageNet    
base_model = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet',pooling=None)
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
predictions = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)
```

Next, I want to feed it to a LSTM network, as follows...

```
final_model = Sequential()
final_model.add((model))
final_model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, stateful=True))
final_model.add(Dense(N, activation='softmax'))
```

But I'm confused how to reshape the output to the LSTM input. My original input is (224*224*3) to CNN. 
Also, should I use TimeDistributed?

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you use imageDataGenerator as preparing image sequences?

Comment: @TheJokerAEZ No, I didn't use ImageDataGenerator. Used pre-saved paths instead...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding an LSTM after a CNN does not make a lot of sense, as LSTM is mostly used for temporal/sequence information, whereas your data seems to be only spatial, however if you still like to use it just use

```
x = Reshape((1024,1))(x)
```

This would convert it to a sequence of 1024 samples, with 1 feature

If you are talking of spatio-temporal data, Use `Timedistributed` on the Resnet Layer and then you can use [`convlstm2d`](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#convlstm2d)

Comment: Thanks, you showed me a direction...
Your first suggestion worked perfect, but I'm considering the fact that you told - it's not making much sense. Infact, yeah, I have spatio-temporal data.


But how can I use TimeDistributed, can you please elaborate for my understanding. I saw this answer at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42313412/keras-pretrain-cnn-with-timedistributed) . The response suggests to "copy the code of ResNet and add TimeDistributed to all layers and then load the weights from a "basic" ResNet on my customized ResNet." Shall I perform this, then?

Comment: Yes exactly, something like `input_layer = Input(shape); base_model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False); x =  TimeDistributed(base_model)(input_layer); x = convlstm2d(params)(x);....; x = TimeDistributed(Dense(N))(x);     `

Answer (score 1):

Example of using pretrained network with LSTM:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(config.N_FRAMES_IN_SEQUENCE, config.IMAGE_H, config.IMAGE_W, config.N_CHANNELS))
cnn = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=(config.IMAGE_H, config.IMAGE_W, config.N_CHANNELS))
x = TimeDistributed(cnn)(inputs)
x = TimeDistributed(Flatten())(x)
x = LSTM(256)(x)
```

Comment: Did you test this? it returns a dimension error. while the VGG16 expects input shape of (batch_size, width, height, dimension), the LSTM expects a sequence (batch_size,timestep, width, height, dimension). I am facing this issue now.